Why an Out Parameter can be left unassigned in .NET 6 but not .NET 8 (CS0177)?
The same code compiles in a .NET 6 project but shows the compile error CS0177 in .NET 8 - why?
It seems like the rule would only be valid for .net8 or some rules have changed.
Since it seems to work in .NET 6...
The app runs in .NET 6 with the output:
Hello, World!
Else: Bad Date Format! 'abc'
01.01.0001

So clearly it uses the default value of the struct. But somehow this is not anymore the case for .NET 8 (I didn't find this documented so far, at least not here)
I tested it with creating 2 new console projects in VS for each version, and also by changing the target framework in both projects with the same result.

CS0177 The out parameter 'parameter' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method
    (does not mention versions)

(Why an Out Parameter can be left unassigned in projects targeting .NET Standard? this did not help at all, it talks only about structs not .net versions)
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        TryParse("abc", out DateOnly d);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static bool TryParse(string s, out DateOnly dateOnly)
    {
        try
        {
            if (s is not null && s.Length == 8)
            {
                int yyyy = int.Parse(s[0..4]);
                int mm = int.Parse(s[4..6]);
                int dd = int.Parse(s[6..8]);
                var date = new DateOnly(yyyy, mm, dd);
                dateOnly = date;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Else: Bad Date Format! '" + s + "'");
                return false; //CS0177 in .net8
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Catch: Bad Date Format! '" + s + "'");
            return false; //CS0177 in .net8
        }
    }
}




This is probably a bug in .NET 6, but I can't find the corresponding issue for it

Interestingly, I get an error on .NET 6 if I replace the DateOnly with a DateTime

Alternately it could be a bug in C#12 (for .NET 8): if the linked Q re. structs is correct as DateOnly has no accessible instance fields.

@Richard I can't repro on .NET 6 with my own struct which has no accessible instance fields: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IzoE02

@Sinatr It's an instance member in DateOnly as well. static wouldn't be representative

I suspect this is a problem with the reference assemblies for .NET 6, but I'm struggling to track them down

FYI: re-creates in C#13 (.NET 9 preview). "Accessible" fields is not the correct criterion; any field in the struct means there is no implicit assignment. See my answer for references.

@Richard It doesn't repro on June's main on sharplab: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxANwKYCcoDMCecAmIA1AD4ACATAIwCwAULAhjBADYAElnVA7PQN712w7gDZOAFnYBZaDAAUZKgAYA2gF12EdAHMAzgEohIwXRHn2AFXQ4ACtr2p5AIgjAAxs7jsA9gFcEdgARCCYAeRhWHHZ8AwBuY2EAX3pEzgBmMUkrG3t0R0UVdj1vf0CQ8Mjo/FDUCKiDdn52FLokoA==

@canton7 I have no idea which runtime/language sharplib is targeting.  And it is now clear to me (having worked through the spec, see my answer) that the lack of an error in .NET 6 is the error here. Given .NET 6 is almost EoL I don't think you'll see a fix.

@Richard One of the runtime developers literally said it was fixed in .NET 7, after one of the compiler team said it was due to an incorrect reference assembly.

@Richard I also can't repro with 9.0.100-preview.7

@canton7 My recreate (used Visual Studio 17.12.0 Preview 1.0): https://gist.github.com/richardcox13/a92d2d9d83d72f8cc872f847dba7a5a6.js

@Richard When you say "re-creates", I assume you mean that you get no error? Since the issue is that there's no error when there should be one

@canton7 NB. by "re-create" I mean I am getting the error (ie. re-create that the error is given for the lack of assignment post .NET 6). I think you are reversing the meaning to me!!

@Richard Right. Yes you will get the error in .NET 7 and later, because they fixed the reference assemblies in .NET 7

@Richard I've found the original issue, PR, and commit which fixed this. It was a problem with the tooling which generates ref assemblies

This is a problem with the reference assemblies in .NET 6. It was fixed in .NET 7.
In C#, a struct is considered "definitely assigned" if it has no fields, see this answer for details.
In .NET 6, the reference assembly for System.Runtime contained a definition for DateOnly and TimeOnly which did not have any fields. The compiler therefore treated it as an empty struct, which didn't need to be explicitly assigned.
See this GitHub issue and this other one for details. This was originally spotted on SO, in this question. It was fixed by changing the tooling which generates the reference assemblies, to include a dummy field in such structs where necessary.
Git claims that the issue was fixed in this commit, but it's not showing up in the diff. I suspect that there's an evil merge in there somewhere which is hiding it.

I think you can remove the word "accessible" - I believe this is one of those occasions where the compiler looks under the bonnet - IIRC a lot of the ref assemblies have things like private readonly bool dummy; - edit: looks like different waves of the "fix" for this had different behaviours - "accessible" was relevant for bullet 1 here, but is not any longer now that the missing fields are (mostly) added, I believe: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29319#issuecomment-414517139

@MarcGravell Yep good point thanks, removed

Isn't this a bug in the compiler that was fixed by changing the reference assembly generation rules, instead of a problem with the reference assemblies themselves? Here it says that even if there is a field in the struct, if that field is of reference type, in another assembly, and private, then the compiler ignores it anyway.

@palapapa Interesting coincidence. DateOnly/TimeOnly don't have a field which is a reference type, so I don't think that applies here? It is also a fact that the reference assemblies were wrong in .NET 6 and didn't contain any fields at all (there's a link in my answer), and the compiler was following the spec when presented with a type with no fields

Linked issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27012 suggests adding <Features>Strict</Features> to your project file as a workaround in .net 6.

@JeremyLakeman That's a different issue I think (the one which palapapa mentioned), which is about the compiler ignoring private reference type fields, not the reference assembly missing private value type fields. I doubt setting Strict would help, as the compiler's behaviour here is correct.

Working through the latest available C# standard (for C# 8, I don't think anything significant has changed specification-wise for out parameters).

15.6.2.3.4 Output parameters


Within a method, just like a local variable, an output parameter is initially considered unassigned and shall be definitely assigned before its value is used. Every output parameter of a method shall be definitely assigned before the method returns.

As expected out parameters must be assigned (so much it is said twice in the same paragraph).

9.4.1 [Definite assignment | ] General


The definite-assignment states of instance variables of a struct_type variable are tracked individually as well as collectively. In additional to the rules described in §9.4.2, §9.4.3, and §9.4.4, the following rules apply to struct_type variables and their instance variables:

An instance variable is considered definitely assigned if its containing struct_type variable is considered definitely assigned.
A struct_type variable is considered definitely assigned if each of its instance variables is considered definitely assigned.


Unlike the referenced Q there is nothing here that talks about "accessible fields": they all need to be "definitely assigned".
Because in some cases the SDK has "façade" assemblies which are different to the runtime (eg. DateOnly is documented to be in System.Runtime but is implemented in System.Private.CoreLib). Sometimes (like DateTime) the documented assembly forwards to the real implementation and thus is resolved by the compiler enforcing this rule. In other cases (and thus has changed over time as an implementation detail) the façade is only resolved by the loader and JIT compiler at runtime and thus the compiler does not see the internals of the type and cannot see there are fields to be assigned.
For obvious performance in the loader/JIT, and definitely for AoT, the case where the façade forwards is likely to be more common now than in the past.
TL/DR: needing the explicit assignment seems to be correct for any struct with any fields accessible or not (and why, for structs, internal changes can be a breaking changes).

Forwarded assemblies aren't relevant to compile-time I think? The compiler relies on reference assemblies only. So "facade" assemblies can't be relevant to this. And I'm not sure how the JIT / AOT is relevant here either. The problem is a compile-time error in one .NET version but not the others. The stuff about "accessible fields" is from "A struct_type variable is considered definitely assigned if each of its instance variables is considered definitely assigned" -- therefore a struct with no fields is always assigned. That, combined with a ref assembly which had no fields, lead to this bug

@canton7 to convert into native machine code the "real" implementation (not some reference sufficient for compilation to IL) is needed. This will be the JIT compiler at runtime, or when doing an AoT compile.

I know. This error is a compiler error -- it's raised by the compiler at compile-time. The JIT is not the one raising the error. Therefore anything related to the JIT, or types in assemblies resolved at runtime, is not, and cannot, be relevant to the question.
